# Need advice about the use of JWT for authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, jwt

While building my website I decided to use JWT for the authentication feature. In the front-end I have React and in back-end Express server with Postgres database.

Right now when user tries to log in, I verify his credentials against the database and then issue a token, which then is stored in http-only cookie in the browser.

However right now I'm struggling with some front-end problems. I need to have some sort of 'CurrentUser' object on the client side. The problem is that I can't decode token and retrieve data from it using React, since it is http-only. I could additionally send user credentials along with the token and then store them in local/session storage, but that doesn't seem secure to me.

Perhaps I misunderstand something about the applications of JWT, if so,  could you please correct me and give some advice about how I should handle my authentication ?

Comment: You should probably review a good summary of how JWT works in practice.  The whole point of JWT is that the incoming token itself contains enough information for the server to decide whether to authenticate or reject the request.

Comment: You never wanna do anything with jwt token on client side other than just sending it back to the server untouched. Maybe create another userinfo api, make http request to this api, have this token decoded at server and send back the user info

Comment: The server validation of token works fine, my problem is that on the client if I want to greet the user who logged in or check his access permissions, where would I get that information from, since the cookie is http-only and I can't decode information from it on the client side ?

Comment: I'm considering **Jay Wadhwa's** solution, would it be a good coding practice ?

Comment: @DmytroYankovskyi: JWs solution makes sense. And you can also include information in the API, e.g. full name, that you don't have in the JWT.

Comment: @jps: so once I get this info, do I store it somewhere like local/session storage or perhaps some observable object in React ? Or you would make calls to this api whenever a request to the authorized route comes from the client ?